# Select query not showing expected result. print_ only shows the first array correctly then a single string of other rows email field

Tags: php, sql, pdo

A table called "checks" has fields ID;email;pass;entered;firstname;lastname;trading.
The only code in this test is the DB connection and the new PDO connection made prior to these snippets.   The following snippet reports correctly that there are 5 users in the table "checks".

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM checks";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '<br>' . $row['num'] . ' users exist.';
```

This snippet which follows immediately after the above doesn't show the expected result.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM checks";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute($id);
$users = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($users);
```

The print_r statement results in the first array being printed correctly with all fields/contents correctly displayed.
On the next line it prints only the email field contents from each row as a single string!

I'm probably missing something obvious but I just can't spot it.  Help please?

Answer (score 0):

`PDO::fetch()` returns a single row from the result set. You need `PDO::fetchAll()` instead.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM checks";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute();
$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // <--- here
```